# Combine objects with overrides

Tags: javascript

I have the following array:

```
var config = {
  default: {
    username: 'bye',
    password: '123',
    tries: 3
  },
  custom: {
    username: 'hello',
    tries: 2
  }
};
```

I need to get the following result from it:

```
var config = {
    username: 'hello',
    password: '123',
    tries: 2
};
```

How can I achieve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How can I merge properties of two JavaScript objects dynamically?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/171251/how-can-i-merge-properties-of-two-javascript-objects-dynamically)

Answer (score 6):

You can use `Object.assign()` to return new object.

```js
var config = {
  default: {
    username: 'bye',
    password: '123',
    tries: 3
  },
  custom: {
    username: 'hello',
    tries: 2
  }
};

var result = Object.assign({}, config.default, config.custom)
console.log(result)
```

Comment: There is special function for it, surprised. thanks.

Comment: Note that `Object.assign` is **ES6** feature, so take care about browser compatibility [Object.assign() Browser compatibility (MDN)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign#Browser_compatibility)

Answer (score 1):

**Another solution** if you want to overwrite the object

Make a loop over `config.custom` object keys, then overwrite the keys

```js
var config = {
  default: {
    username: 'bye',
    password: '123',
    tries: 3
  },
  custom: {
    username: 'hello',
    tries: 2
  }
};

  for (var key in config.custom) { 
    config.default[key] = config.custom[key]; 
  }

console.log(config.default);
```